# When accessing assigned private variables, they return 0

Tags: java, android, colors, private-members

I have a class that extends view. Below, is the constructor. In the constructor I assign values to `private int r,g,b;`. The correct values are assigned.

```
public CanvasView(Context c, int r, int g, int b) {
        super(c);
        context = c;
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;

    Log.i("RGB:", "r" + r + "g" + g + "b" + b); //logs correct values

}
```

In onDraw (see below), when I access the values all of them are zero.

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        hsv = new float[3];

        Color.RGBToHSV(r, g, b, hsv);

        hsv[2] = getVal();

        Log.i("RGBdraw:", "r" + r + "g" + g + "b" + b); //values are all 0

        if (canvas != null){

            canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
        }



    }
```

I thought that when assigning private variables, they can be access class-wide? 
Any help is much appreciated thanks.

**Edit**
Here is the minimal example

In another class I create the view `CanvasView mCanvasView = new CanvasView(mContext, 255, 0, 171);`

Below is the class, called CanvasView, which gets created by the code above. I pass 3 integers to CanvasView.

```
public class CanvasView extends View {

private Context context;
private int r,g,b;

public CanvasView(Context c, int r, int g, int b) {
    super(c);
    context = c;
    this.r = r;
    this.g = g;
    this.b = b;

    Log.i("RGB:", "r" + r + "g" + g + "b" + b); //Correct values are logged

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Log.i("RGB draw:", "r" + r + "g"+g + "b"+b); //Values here are all 0

    if (canvas != null){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You thought correctly.  So please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: per [kor88](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4884718/kor88)  Try to debug your code. Make sure you apply onDraw(...) method to the same object you created with the constructor you described above. If the object is the same use debug to understand where the variables get changed to 0s. Good luck!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I posted complete example :)

Comment: @HaloMediaz It is practically not possible for something like that to happen. I am sure you have your log statements messed up (since the log statement in both versions of your CanvasView class don't match). Take a closer look at your code an ensure that you are looking at the correct log statement in the logs.

Comment: Looks like the object (CanvasView) you use to do onDraw() isn't initiated trough your constructor. Unless you have some other code to modify your private members.

Comment: @ChetanKinger It can't be the log statements as color drawn is black (RGB: 000). Here is a screenshot of the logs: http://i.imgur.com/j2AZlgf.png

Comment: @HaloMediaz The point I am trying to make is that you have shown 2 conflicting lines of code in your question 1. `Log.i("RGBdraw:"` and 2)  `Log.i("RGB draw:"`. This makes me question the correctness of the code you have posted.

Comment: is your private Context object == null?

Comment: @User404 You where right. Here is what worked: final CanvasView mView = (CanvasView) findViewById(R.id.canvasView);

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating the class, like you would in java: `CanvasView mCanvasView = new CanvasView(mContext, 255, 0, 171);`

create the class the android way: `CanvasView mView = (CanvasView) findViewById(R.id.canvasView);`

Then use getters and setters for Red Green Blue

```
public void red(int r){
        this.r = r;
    }

    public int getRed(){
        return r;
    }
```

Pass values like so: `mView.red(255);`